# fusion tables kml import incomplete

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm importing a KML file into fusion tables and am seeing missing rows - I only get the first 4 rows.  I checked the file in Google Earth and all the polygons show up fine, so I feel confident that the KML file isn't corrupt.

When I first open the file in Google Drive tables it has a note that it is 17% imported, but then that dissapeared.  It seems like the import isn't completing.  The file is 20MB.

Any tips or suggestions.  I looked around on here and didn't see a similar problem.
Pointers appreciated!

*PS: you an try the file here if you are interested in the question:
  http://temp.rahulbotics.com/chna.kml.zip*

Comment: hmm.... maybe this is due to the million-character limit I see mentioned on [their documentation](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171181#kml)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed that my polygon was too long (breaking the length limit in Fusion Tables).  I used a quick sed command to reduce the significant digits of my coordinates down significantly, and then it imported fine!

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{4\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g' orig.kml > trimmed5.kml
```